# Seemingly incorrect Operator Precedence

Tags: sql-server

I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around some operator precedence, where I'm expecting *all* of the queries below to fail; this is based on the documentation below where Division would be evaluated before Comparison operators.

> Microsoft documentation for t-sql Operator Precedence: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Sample data and queries

```
CREATE TABLE #orders(
    price INT
)
GO 

INSERT INTO #orders VALUES 
(1)
,(2)
,(3)
,(4)
,(5)
,(6)
,(7)
,(8)
,(9)
,(10)
,(0)  

GO

/*
the following two queries work
*/
SELECT * 
FROM   #orders 
WHERE  2 / price > 0 
       AND price > 0; 

SELECT * 
FROM   #orders 
WHERE  price > 0 
       AND 2 / price > 0; 

/*
these don't work - getting divide by zero error
*/
SELECT * 
FROM   #orders 
WHERE  2 / price > 0 
       AND price IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                      5, 6, 7, 8, 
                      9, 10 ); 

SELECT * 
FROM   #orders 
WHERE  price IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                  5, 6, 7, 8, 
                  9, 10 ) 
       AND 2 / price > 0;
```

> Shared Execution plan for one of the working queries: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJFH3JWB7
>
> Shared (estimated) Execution plan for one of the non-working queries: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1Ds2yWSQ

Any help in understanding this behavior would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Eli

Comment: You can prevent with an index but very odd and looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Can you please elaborate on how an index would affect the query plan?

Comment: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_p ON #orders (price);

Comment: @CetinBasoz that's a what to do, though it doesn't explain why that works.

Comment: Why did the optimizer use the NonClustered index when it isn't any narrower than the Clustered index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. I think that perhaps the language on the [documentation page that you shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a touch imprecise, which is probably contributing to your confusion. Here's a quote (emphasis mine):

> When a complex expression has multiple operators, operator precedence
>   determines the **sequence** in which the operations are performed. The
>   **order of execution** can significantly affect the resulting value.

The strong implication here is that precedence and order of execution are essentially the same thing, but they're not. [Eric Lippert explains this](https://ericlippert.com/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/) better than I ever could (emphasis in the original).

> **Precedence** rules describe how an underparenthesized expression should
>   be parenthesized *when the expression mixes different kinds of
>   operators*. For example, multiplication is of higher precedence than
>   addition, so 2 + 3 x 4 is equivalent to 2 + (3 x 4), not (2 + 3) x 4.
>
> **Associativity** rules describe how an underparenthesized expression
>   should be parenthesized when the expression has a bunch of the same
>   kind of operator. For example, addition is associative from left to
>   right, so a + b + c is equivalent to (a + b) + c, not a + (b + c). In
>   ordinary arithmetic, these two expressions always give the same
>   result; in computer arithmetic, they do not necessarily. (As an
>   exercise can you find values for a, b, c such that (a + b) + c is
>   unequal to a + (b + c) in C#?)
>
> Now the confusing one.
>
> **Order of evaluation** rules describe the order in which each operand in
>   an expression is evaluated. The parentheses just describe how the
>   results are grouped together; “do the parentheses first” is not a rule
>   of C#. Rather, the rule in C# is “evaluate each subexpression strictly
>   left to right”.

Read the whole thing. Eric uses C# and C++ as his examples but his comments apply a lot more generally than that. As he suggests, if you think of operator precedence rules as controlling how the components of an expression are grouped rather than the order in which they're executed, the behavior you're seeing makes a lot more sense. Here's a simplified version of one of the queries that you understandably expected to fail, but which actually succeeded:

```
declare @t table (x int);
insert @t values (0);

select * from @t where 2 / x > 0 and x > 0;
```

SQL Server's operator precedence rules simply mean that the above query is equivalent to:

```
-- Same query as above with operator precedence shown explicitly.
select * from @t where ((2 / x) > 0) and (x > 0);
```

The interesting thing about `AND` in this context is that if you know one of its operands is false, then you know that the entire expression is false without even evaluating the other operand. Some programming languages specify the order in which the operand evaluation will occur. For instance, [the && operator in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) evaluates its left-hand operand first, and if it's false, it does not evaluate its right-hand operand at all. But the [`AND` operator in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) makes no claims one way or the other; it is up to the optimizer to choose.

There have been a lot of articles devoted to exploring this behavior in detail; for instance, [here is a pretty detailed one](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71950/). Does this help at all?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has to do with the operator precedence but what order the optimizer chooses to evaluate the where clause.

In the first two, the rows must be filtered `where price > 0` *first* preventing the error.

Since the second two use `IN`, the division must be occurring first to limit the rows, and then the `IN` filter is evaluated.  This can be prevented by adding an index... i.e. make `ID` a primary key, which creates a clustered index, and you won't get the error since the optimizer can use the index and filter the rows before the division, or choose to.

The predicate should change from `price > 0 AND 2 / price > 0` to `2/price > 0`

Comment: Very odd since doing division first wouldn't limit the rows.

Comment: can you elaborate @CetinBasoz? Division by itself wouldn't but evaluating the division part of the where clause would, `where 2 / price > 0`

Comment: Try with say price IN (1,3,4). Which one limits the rows? IN or doing division per row? If you are doing division per row, what are you limiting? BTW what does "2/price" mean? Are you saying spaces change the result?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The combined where clause would limit the rows where price in (1,3,4) AND the 2 / price > 0. The optimizer could choose which order to evaluate these. So, it could evaluate 2 / price > 0 first, and then price in (1,3,4), or visa versa. The index makes the optimizer choose an order which prevents the error for this simple example, but the index likely wouldn't prevent this in more complex queries containing more joins, or more conditions in the where clause.

Comment: Yes, I meant optimizer is not limiting correctly and it is unlikely one would have an index on price. Probably best solution would be to have price > 0 check.

Comment: Correctly is subjective here, but this is where query hints can help. Dr. DeWitt explains who query optimization is so difficult... given the trillions of possibilites: https://youtu.be/RQfJkNqmHB4

Comment: @scsimon firstly, thanks for the answer and the vid, I'll dig deeper into those now. Note: for the failing queries, the query plan shows that it converts the `IN(1,2,..)` clause into individual `[tempdb].[dbo].[#orders].[price]=(1) OR...`. This explains why those fail, though either query should need to filter out those records where price > 0 - which means that neither query will ever run a comparison which actually divides by zero...

Answer (score 0):

Actually my preference would be to change the expression (it is unlikely you would have an index on price - or simply make it robust with or without index):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   #orders 
WHERE CASE WHEN price > 0 THEN 2/price ELSE 0 END > 0 AND
      price IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                  5, 6, 7, 8, 
                  9, 10 );
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for an answer on how to write a query which will succeed; rather, I was trying to understand what was happening.